# set username in socket io connection

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets

I have a chat application where I have to handle online users. 
How can i send user name in:

```
    var myIoSocket = io.connect();
```

So i can make a list at the backend.

currently i am doing like this.

```
Socket.on("connect",function(){
            Notification.primary('Connected');
            Socket.emit('iamonline',{
                username: $rootScope.username
            });
        });
```

Backend :

```
var onlineUsers = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('iamonline',function (data) {
        console.log(data.username," connected.")
        onlineUsers[data.username] = socket;
        Users[data.username] = socket;
        currentUser = data.username;
        console.log(socket)
        io.sockets.emit("liveusers",Object.keys(onlineUsers));
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        delete onlineUsers[currentUser];
        console.log(currentUser," disconnected.");
        io.sockets.emit("liveusers",Object.keys(onlineUsers));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue for a different project and found out the best way to do it with query and get value on handshake.

server.js

```
io.on('connection' , function(socket){
  if(typeof socket.handshake.name!="undefined"){
    user = {
      name : socket.handshake.query.name,
      id : socket.handshake.query.id,
      email : socket.handshake.query.email,
    }
  }
});
```

on client side,

```
if(typeof io != "undefined"){
  var visitor = io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000' , {
        'query': $.param({token: '<?=Session::$instance->session['id']?>'}) + '&name=<?=Session::get("username")?>&id=<?=Session::get("ID")?>&email=<?=Sesion::get("Email")?>'
  });
}
```